# TypeScript express router.use() Argument type does not match parameters in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I'm currently dealing with a strange issue using WebStorm (2017.1.3, which is the latest as of now, May 2017).

While I code in TypeScript, and use Router of Express.js, WebStorm keeps me telling 'Argument types do not match parameters' in the following usage of API.

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {IRouter, NextFunction, Router} from "express-serve-static-core";

let router: Router = express.Router();

// works
router.get("/", () => {}); 

// complaining
router.use("/", (req, res, next) => {}); 

// complaining
router.use("/", (req: express.Response, res: express.Response, next: NextFunction) => {});
```

I can't figure out why WebStorm keeps me saying that, when I see that VSCode does see the exact same code as having no problem at all.

In fact this code gets compiled flawlessly with tsc, and I know I can suppress type mismatch complaining in WebStorm. It is rather I'd just want to know why this happens.

For your information, type definitions for express.js looks as following

```
interface IRouter extends RequestHandler {
  // ... 
  use: IRouterHandler<this> & IRouterMatcher<this>;
}

interface IRouterHandler<T> {
  (...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
  (...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
} 

interface IRouterMatcher<T> {
  (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
  (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
}

// ...
```

Has anyone ever seen a similar issue? or do I miss something?